# Command C-M-<SPC> not working on mac os high sierra

Tags: osx

I have emacs 25.2 installed on my Mac. Yesterday I updated the OS to High Sierra and the command `C-M-<SPC>` to highlight s-expressions is not working any more. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Emacs 26.0, upgraded to High Sierra, C-M-spc works as expected (calls `mark-sexp`)

Comment: UPDATE: I installed emacs 25.3. the binding still doesn't work but I found that `mark-sexp` is also bound to `C-M-@` and that works

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with Emacs for MacOS, on HighSierra. The `C-M-g` combination works. `C-SPC` and `M-SPC` both work. But `C-M-SPC` seems to not send a signal to the emacs system. Very bizarre. Any ideas here?

Comment: Is it gui emacs or emacs -nw?

Comment: `Esc C-SPC` seems to work...

Comment: Have you checked whether there are any OS level shortcuts set up? I think you have to look under the keyboard settings and the accessibility section too. (Something keeps turning on a C-SPC shortcut on my Mac.)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @MaximKim It's Gui Emacs. MacOS 10.13.3 (Emacs 25.3).

Comment: @AlanThird I checked the OS level keyboard mappings. And the alt key is sending the correct (alt) modifier signal, as expected. And that works for `M-SPC`. But for some reason, when I do `C-M-SPC`, no signal is sent.

Comment: What happens when you 1. open emacs with `emacs -Q` and press `C-h k` `C-M-SPC`?

Comment: 10.15.7 High Sierra, I've tried all the workaround that previously existed but no matter what macOS still gobbles up C-M-SPC. On other apps it brings up the Character Viewer to insert emojis, but Apple really doesn't want you to unbind that keymapping for whatever reason. Even if you change shortcut key for All Applications->Emojis & Symbols (which bring sup the Character Viewer) it still will hog the C-M-SPC keybinding.

Answer (score 2):

I always switched 'option' with 'command' for emacs in OS X.

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier 'super)
```

Given these key bindings in OS X (10.13.4) and Emacs (25.3, installed via homebrew), the `C-M-<SPC>` works as expected on my mac.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. And I don't know why. I'm on MacOS 10.13.3 (Emacs 25.3). I previously had `(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)`, which worked. Using `(setq mac-option-modifier 'super)` stops the meta key from working altogether. And again, `M-SPC` works. But for some reason, when I do `C-M-SPC`, no signal is sent. Even when setting both `mac-command-modifier` and `mac-option-modifier`.

Comment: Can you check if emacs can catch your key inputs with `c-h k` followed by `C-M-SPC`? If not, it's the OS X that catch the key sequence, then you may need to check which one occupy that key bindings by checking `system preferences` -> `keyboard` -> `shortcuts`. If yes, Emacs is catching the key bindings, you will also know which function has been attached to the key bindings, you can change that keybindings by rebinding the keys via `define-key` .etc.

Comment: @Nutritioustim, if your Emacs is built with Cocoa, the key modifiers should be ```ns-alternate-modifier``` and ```ns-command-modifier```. As is revealed [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems), ```mac-modif...``` might be of interest, but it ought to be true by default. Check also your keyboard settings for the Ctrl-Opt-Space, may be assigned to some other OS command (this is my case, and disabling that command make the C-M-<SPC> working when I check it with Emacs -Q).

Comment: @phye Yes, that was it. In `system preferences` -> `keyboard` -> `shortcuts`, `C-M-Space` was being captured by **Input Sources** > **Select next source in input menu**. Cheers.